C# - Editing PDF content
A PDF file has textboxes. The file contains textboxes, images, objects and table. The textboxes contain text. I would like to write a C# script that will run through an Excel file and take the data from the Excel file and past it into a particular location in the textboxes in the PDF file and update the PDF file and copying over everything else in the PDF file then save it. Do I need to find the exact coordinates of each object and text in the PDF file to do this? Is it even possible to do this?
Input PDF File:

Update PDF File:


Ok i see. So you think I should create a new PDF with the  updated information on it instead of updated the old PDF, correct?

You need to use different library like
To Read data from the Excel file: Use a library like EPPlus or ClosedXML.
Manipulate the PDF file: Use a library like iTextSharp or PdfSharp to manipulate the PDF file.
e.g
form.SetField("TextBox1", excelData[0, 0]);

Update textboxes in the PDF: Use the PDF library to find and update the textboxes with the data from the Excel file.
Save the updated PDF file: Save the changes to a new PDF file.

The easiest way to build a visible template ONCE is use a GUI editor. as you can tweak the desired working areas. Then use programming for import and export of FDF data. At the end shot, I show that one FDF can be imported by a PDF Reader (then saved). But for a program approach you use either an SDK or a single command line utility (much simpler).
The tricky bit is the text editing separate FDF files, where your skill in C# will be challenged, compared to my MS Notepad for proof of concept (and errors).
When using PDF as a Template the concept is the fields are import/exportable. thus no need for a PDF editor as either a user or a base of data files can edit the fields without writing PDF core edits.
Here we have 6 fields (3 on each page) to represent the initial states before changes normally we would just have the 3 fields in an empty template.

Normaly an imported field entry would simply be:
/T (Text1)
/V (Location 1:\rInstall\rNail 5"\rDrywall Sheet\rRemove\rNail 5"\r \r )

Because you want to include underlines we need to use "Rich Text", which makes the task a little harder. SO I show the FDF import needed for the first box expanded but 2 and 3 left condensed.
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF <<
/Fields [<<
/RV (<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acroform:2.7.0.0" xfa:spec="2.1" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;text-valign:top;">
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Location 1:</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Install</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 5&quot;</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Drywall Sheet</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Remove</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 5&quot;</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;"><span style="xfa-spacerun:yes">&#160;</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;"><span style="xfa-spacerun:yes">&#160;</span></p></body>)
/T (Text1)
/V (Location 1:\rInstall\rNail 5"\rDrywall Sheet\rRemove\rNail 5"\r \r )
>> <<
/RV (<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acroform:2.7.0.0" xfa:spec="2.1" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;text-valign:top;"><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Location 2:</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Install</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 5&quot;</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Drywall Sheet</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Remove</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 3&quot;</span></p></body>)
/T (Text2)
/V (Location 2:\rInstall\rNail 5"\rDrywall Sheet\rRemove\rNail 3")
>> <<
/RV (<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acroform:2.7.0.0" xfa:spec="2.1" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;text-valign:top;"><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Location 3:</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Install</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 5&quot;</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Drywall Sheet</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Remove</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 3&quot;</span></p></body>)
/T (Text3)
/V (Location 3:\rInstall\rNail 5"\rDrywall Sheet\rRemove\rNail 3")
>>
]
/ID [<DCAFF9351A0FCC8C15F7F66FDC368E61> <DCAFF9351A0FCC8C15F7F66FDC368E61>]
>>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF

You want the fields to include Pillar Window x 10 on 2 lines in different places so we need to add those as both plain and rich text at the desired locations.
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF <<
/Fields [<<
/RV (<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acroform:2.7.0.0" xfa:spec="2.1" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;text-valign:top;">
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Location 1:</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Install</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 5&quot;</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Pillar</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Widow10</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Drywall Sheet</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Remove</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 5&quot;</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;"><span style="xfa-spacerun:yes">&#160;</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;"><span style="xfa-spacerun:yes">&#160;</span></p></body>)
/T (Text1)
/V (Location 1:\rInstall\rNail 5"\rPiller\rWindowx10\rDrywall Sheet\rRemove\rNail 5"\r \r )
>> <<
/RV (<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acroform:2.7.0.0" xfa:spec="2.1" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;text-valign:top;"><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Location 2:</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Install</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 5&quot;</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Drywall Sheet</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Remove</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 3&quot;</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Pillar</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Widow10</span></p></body>)
/T (Text2)
/V (Location 2:\rInstall\rNail 5"\rDrywall Sheet\rRemove\rNail 3"\rPiller\rWindowx10)
>> <<
/RV (<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acroform:2.7.0.0" xfa:spec="2.1" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;text-valign:top;"><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Location 3:</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Install</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 5&quot;</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Pillar</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Widow10</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Drywall Sheet</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline;color:#FF0000;"><span>Remove</span></p><p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Nail 3&quot;</span></p></body>)
/T (Text3)
/V (Location 3:\rInstall\rNail 5"\rPiller\rWindowx10\rDrywall Sheet\rRemove\rNail 3")
>>
]
/ID [<DCAFF9351A0FCC8C15F7F66FDC368E61> <DCAFF9351A0FCC8C15F7F66FDC368E61>]
>>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF

Now when we simply command line or double click for importing the bulk changes, then the templates will differ. and fields 1-3 will be as desired.
Forgive the use of overlaid colours on your image as your template will be cleaner from scratch.
Spot my many errors I forgot to read and copy Window x 10 in the rich lines and used \rWindowx10 without spacing in the others, plus interchanged Piller & Pillar thus another 3 wrong! You will not make the same mistooks?
<p style="margin-left:5pt;font-family:Arial;color:#FF0000;"><span>Widow10</span></p>


